# Start and stop EC2 and then enable/check services on instance using bash

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I need to stop start multiple EC2 instances and run few command after they start, using bash on the same manage server without needing to ssh.

I know how to start and stop EC2 instances, for example:

start instance:

```
#! /bin/bash
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234
```

Stop instance:

```
#! /bin/bash
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234
```

I figured how to list all EC2 IDs by running:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId] --output text
```

My questions are:

1. How can I stop/start multiple EC2 instances?
2. How can I grab a specific EC2 instance and run a command to check a service enabled after the instance started?

May be I need to run `if` condition to compare the id or tag name with the EC2 instance needed then run the shell command?

I know the logic but please help me with the script details.

Answer (score 0):

You can **start/stop multiple instances** by specifying their IDs:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234 i-1a1235 i-1a1236
```

If you want to **run a script on an instance** *every time it starts*, you can put the script in:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

This will use `cloud-init` to automatically run the script, which can then do whatever checking/processing you wish.

When your program on the instance has finished its processing, it can stop its own instance with:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

For more details, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Alternatively, you cold use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to run a script on the instance. This is a great way to run jobs on instances that are already running. The command can even be executed on multiple instances simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you John for answering my first question, I might did not explain my issue. so I have 5 ec2 , one of them I need to stop oracle gracefully before I stop it, When I stop it  manually I usually ssh to it and run : "su - grid " (it is the oracle user) then I run 
"crsctl stop has" (to stop oracle) so i need run these command from the script on the oracle ec2
I am managing to run the script from crontab and can't use ssm.

Comment: So what is your actual problem? If you want to stop Oracle and then stop the instance, then the _same script_ could do both -- first using `crsctl stop has`, then by using `sudo shutdown now -h`. (You _might_ have problems with a single script jumping between users with `su` -- it will take some testing to confirm.)